# Start only some chapters on right-hand side after a set page/chapter

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters, double-sided

I'm working on my masters thesis, and have a fairly decent structure (I feel..), but I have one issue. I want my chapters to start on the right-hand side, which in itself is not hard to do. However, I've characterized my abstracts(2 of them, an english and a norwegian version) and acknowledgements as chapters, and also the /listoffigures and /listoftables are  affected by this right-hand rule in the command: \documentclass[twoside,openright,11pt,a4paper]{report}
So, my question is: Is there a way to start the right-hand chapters after a set page, or after a set chapter?

The implementation I use on my .tex file is this:

```
    \documentclass[twoside,openright,11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{Chapters/myStyle}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
%\fancyfoot[LO[{}
\cfoot{}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        %
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{img/Universitas.jpg} ~\\[1cm]
        \textsc{\LARGE University of ...}\\[1.5cm]
        \textsc{\Large Masterthesis}\\[0.5cm]
        %
        \rule[0.4cm]{14cm}{0.2pt}\\
        { \huge \bfseries Title... \\[0.4cm] }
        \rule[1.5cm]{14cm}{0.2pt}\\
        %
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushleft} \large
                \emph{Author:}\\
                Firstname \textsc{Lastname}
            \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}
        %
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushright} \large
                \emph{Supervisor:} \\
                Prof.~Firstname \textsc{Lastname}\\
            \end{flushright}
        \end{minipage}
        %
        \vfill
        {\large \today}
        %
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\input{Chapters/Abstract}
\input{Chapters/Abstrakt}
\input{Chapters/Acknowledgements}

\tableofcontents 
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\input{Chapters/Introduction}
\input{Chapters/Theory}
\input{Chapters/Method}
\input{Chapters/Results}
\input{Chapters/Summary}
\input{Chapters/Future_work}
\input{Chapters/AppendixA}
\input{Chapters/AppendixB}
\input{Chapters/AppendixC}
\input{Chapters/AppendixD}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Chapters/Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

I have a .sty file also, which looks like this:

```
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{SIunits}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nooneline]{caption}
%\usepackage[norsk]{babel} %For implementation of norwegian letters æøå
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\includeonly{biblio}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{anysize}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
    %\vskip 40\p@
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
    %\vskip 40\p@
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Regards,
T

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I'm not sure to understand. Issuing `\cleardoublepage` before the contents you want on the right-sided page does what you want?

Comment: @karlkoeller Do you mean implementing it before my importation of each chapter I don't want to start on the right-hand side? I tried that, it still doesn't remove the double pages from the chapters I want it to.
Regards,
T

Comment: Oh, now I understand. See if my answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution can be to redefine `\cleardoublepage` to be `\clearpage` locally to those chapters when you don't want that behavior.

So just write

```
{\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage%
\input{Chapters/Abstract}
\input{Chapters/Abstrakt}
\input{Chapters/Acknowledgements}

\tableofcontents 
\listoftables
\listoffigures
}
```

and you should obtain what you want.

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you so much! 
Best regards,
T